# How to use VueJS with Typescript?

Tags: typescript2.0, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn Vue and Typescript. But I can't seem to set it up correctly.

I made an app.ts file with these lines of code:

```
import { Vue } from "../libs/vue/vue";

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

I thought this would compile to something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

But instead I'm getting tons of errors when I run tsc. It seems as if it is trying to build the Vue definition files? [image: Image here]

How can I get started working on Vue then with typescript? Are there any tutorials that can help me with this? I found a few online but none seem to be helping, or they are using other libraries such as av-ts which gives me the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official document.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Also, why are you importing Vue from "../libs/vue/vue"?
That may be the cause of the problem.
If you have installed Vue.js with `npm install vue`, you should write

```
import Vue = require('vue');
```

or

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it still gives me errors with the .d.ts files

Comment: Oh I found the problem. After checking the detailed MsBuild logs I saw VS was using Typescript 1.8. So after installing [Typescript 2.1.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) it worked!